# Event Listener disappearing after arrow click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm manipulating a wordpress plugin (Spider Calendar) to have some colors change on click. When the page is first loaded, the event listener is listed in the inspector. When you click "2016", "2018", the left arrow, or the right arrow, the event listener disappears from the "event listeners" tab of the inspector, although it still shows in the source code.

From some research, I think this might be happening because the elements are being destroyed? What can I do to have the event listener reload every time the calendar does? Or is there another source of the problem?

My event listener:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("bounce-houses/") > -1) {
  var element = $('#afterbig1 table table table tr:nth-child(n+2) td');
  element.click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":nth-last-child(2)") || $(this).is(":last-child") || $(this).is(":first-child")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("selectedWeekend");
      if ($(this).hasClass("calsun_days")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("sundays");
        $(this).toggleClass("calsun_days");
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("sundays")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("sundays");
        $(this).toggleClass("calsun_days");
      }
    } else if ($(this).is('td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5)')) {
      $(this).toggleClass("selectedDays");
    }
  });
}
});
```

problem page: (The calendar code is too many characters to add here)

[johnabounceandplay.com/bounce-houses/combo-house](http://johnabounceandplay.com/bounce-houses/combo-house)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element is being destroyed no listeners will re attached to it after recreation,

A quick solution is to bind the click event to some element that will always be there, e.g. `body`

Please try the following:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("bounce-houses/") > -1){

    $('body').on('click', '#afterbig1 table table table tr:nth-child(n+2) td', function() {
        if($(this).is(":nth-last-child(2)") || $(this).is(":last-child") || $(this).is(":first-child")){
            $(this).toggleClass("selectedWeekend");
            if($(this).hasClass("calsun_days")){
                $(this).toggleClass("sundays");
                $(this).toggleClass("calsun_days");
            } 
            else if ($(this).hasClass("sundays")){
                $(this).toggleClass("sundays");
                $(this).toggleClass("calsun_days");
            } 
        }

        else if($(this).is('td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5)')){
            $(this).toggleClass("selectedDays");
        }
    })

}
});
```